# Which file formats can I save a pyspark dataframe as?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, pyspark, hiveql

I would like to save a huge pyspark dataframe as a Hive table. How can I do this efficiently? I am looking to use *saveAsTable(name, format=None, mode=None, partitionBy=None, **options)* from *pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable*.

```
# Let's say I have my dataframe, my_df
# Am I able to do the following?
my_df.saveAsTable('my_table')
```

My question is which formats are available for me to use and where can I find this information for myself? Is OrcSerDe an option? I am still learning about this. Thank you.

Comment: You can think of compression since your dataframe is huge

Answer (score 4):

Following file formats are supported.

- text
- csv
- ldap
- json
- parquet
- orc

**Referece:** https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to write the pyspark dataframe to a compressed Hive table by using a *pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter*. To do this I had to do something like the following:

```
my_df.write.orc('my_file_path')
```

That did the trick.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.write

I am using pyspark 1.6.0 btw